# How to find the all the intermediate Towers ids while we are calling from one android mobile to another android mobile?

Tags: android-emulator

Here I am calling from one android cellular phone to another. Both were GSM and we will provide the other cellular phone number like 1234567890 and I have to find all the intermediate tower ids. And i have to display that information on the calling mobile(through the app that we have developed).

Comment: Anybody please help and thanks regards in advance.....